# Carbon datetime not working for sum amount laravel

Tags: laravel

i want to sum amount logs created today in my Repeat table in database i tried followings but not working

```
 $start = (new Carbon('now'))->hour(0)->minute(0)->second(0);
$end = (new Carbon('now'))->hour(23)->minute(59)->second(59);
$data['daily'] = Repeat::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->where('created_at',[$start , $end])->sum('amount');
```

also tried

```
  $start = carbon::today();
$data['daily'] = Repeat::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->where('created_at',$start)->sum('amount');
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `whereBetween`? https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#where-clauses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get today's record by using `carbon` you can do it as below.

```
$data['daily'] = Repeat::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today())->sum('amount');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Carbon::now() or Carbon::today() but check this amount should be integer or float if it string then sum will be 0(zero)

````
$data['daily'] = Repeat::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->whereDate('created_at', Carbon::now())->sum('amount');```
````